# Is there a digital/ultrasonic Anemometer for Arduino?

Tags: sensors

I use Arduino DUE and I noticed that many forum users use the TX-23U Wind Sensor.

[https://www.amazon.com/Crosse-Technology-TX-23U-Weather-Stations/dp/B0016MYA7U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0016MYA7U)

Also, many people tried to create a DIY ultrasonic anemometer like this;
https://soldernerd.com/category/arduino-ultrasonic-anemometer/

Instead of using the DIY ultrasonic anemometer, I wanted to purchase one but I couldn't find one.

Is there an ultrasonic anemometer which I can purchase and connect it with my Arduino DUE?

3.3V power, non-mechanical rotation, I2C/SPI/UART support are the requirements. Thanks.

Comment: When I googled "ultrasonic anemometer" I found various suppliers, though I don't know, if these comply to your specifications or how expensive they are. Have you looked through the google results? I would think, that an ultrasonic anemometer is somewhat niche and this site is not meant for product recommendation, so you might not get a good answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame challenge: pick a sensor that complies with your needs and specification - especially the performance characteristics you're interested in, e.g. range of wind speed to measure, required accuracy and resolution, response time and data acquisition rate, to name just a few. Don't look for something specific to Arduinos to not unnecessarily narrowing down your options. Then design or adapt an appropriate interface to make them both work together.

Common interfaces of "industrial grade" ultrasonic anemometers (e.g. [1](https://www.thiesclima.com/en/Products/Wind-Ultrasonic-Anemometer/) and [2](http://gillinstruments.com/products/anemometer/anemometer.htm)) are RS232/RS422/485, so technically UART, though in need of level shifters or a RS-485/RS-422 transceiver, e.g. [Maxim](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/transceivers/rs-485-rs-422-transceivers.html). Some also offer analogue output that might be feed into an Arduino's analogue in after matching voltage levels.

I would assume that I2C/SPI are rather uncommon as these are for short-distance, intra-board communication not for connecting a separate sensor module.

The same thought applies to the power supply, I recommend to drop the requirement of powering the sensor with 3V3 put rather select a power supply for a sensor available and affordable. The anemometers available at the linked vendors typically list a supply voltage of 5-30VDC or 6-24VDC.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this one: SONIC-ANEMO-MICRO
https://lcjcapteurs.com/en/girouette-anemometres-capteur-vent/sa-micro-2/